# 'undefined is not a function' with google charts when using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I have some JSON data and wanted to try out google charts. I used examples from the documentation from [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) and [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

```
 <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "get-stats.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      var options = {
        title: 'Stats'
      };    
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart =  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
```

When `chart.draw()` gets called, an error "undefined is not a function" appears on the site.

My JSON file gets loaded like this (get-stats.php)

```
<?php 

$string = file_get_contents("stats.json");
echo $string;

?>
```

The JSON is formatted like that:

```
{
    "cols":  [
                 {
                     "id":  "date",
                     "label":  "Date",
                     "type":  "datetime"
                 },
                 {
                     "id":  "cntall",
                     "label":  "Total",
                     "type":  "number"
                 },
                 {
                     "id":  "cntpers",
                     "label":  "Pers",
                     "type":  "number"
                 }
             ],
    "rows":  [
                 {
                     "c":  [
                               {
                                   "v":  "new Date(2013, 11, 17, 9, 54, 0)"
                               },
                               {
                                   "v":  320
                               },
                               {
                                   "v":  123
                               }
                           ]
                 },
                 {
                     "c":  [
                               {
                                   "v":  "new Date(2013, 11, 17, 11, 4, 0)"
                               },
                               {
                                   "v":  300
                               },
                               {
                                   "v":  67
                               }
                           ]
                 }
              ]
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the JSON. All the code is from the google examples.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem myself.

Instead of `"new Date(2013, 11, 17, 9, 54, 0)"` in the JSON-File, I used `"Date(2013,11,17,9,54,0)"` . I don't know why the former didn't work, considering it was described like that in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) at the section "Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter"

Comment: FYI, a javascript literal object is not the same as a JSON string.  Date objects are not valid JSON, so the Visualization API specifies a custom format to input dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($jsonData);
```

Try this instead

```
$jsondata => json_encode($jsonData);
```

and put that with in php tag